# How to set registers of an external ADC

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, avr

I am new to microcontrollers, and I am trying to read external [ADC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog-to-digital_converter) values. Initially I have to setup ADC registers. I am using [SPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus) communication to read ADC values. I am using [AD7798](http://www.analog.com/en/analog-to-digital-converters/ad-converters/ad7798/products/product.html) ADC. I have checked some registers are not configured. To configure registers in ADC AD7798, I have to use the communication register to select which register I want to configure. For example, I want to set configuration register (16-bit) of AD7798. I have written it like this:

```
#include <io.h> 
#define ADC_CS PORTB.3 
#define WG_CS  PORTB.4 
#define MOSI   PORTB.5 
#define MISO_PU PORTB.6 
#define MISO_PIN PINB.6 
#define SCK    PORTB.7 

//global functions.
unsigned int adcConfig;
unsigned int adcMode;
unsigned int adcId;

void init_io(void) 
{ 
DDRB = 0xBF;        // make SCK, MOSI, CS1, CS2 outputs 
ADC_CS = 1;              //disable ADC 
WG_CS = 1;               //disable WaveGenerator 
MISO_PU = 1;             //enable pull-up on MISO so we can test !RDY 
} 

unsigned char spi(unsigned char data) 
{ 
//Start transmision 
SPDR = data; 
//Wait for transmision complete 
while (!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF))); 
return SPDR; 
} 


unsigned int ReadAdIdReg(void) 
{              

SPCR = 0x5D;  
ADC_CS = 0;          
while (MISO_PIN != 0) ; 
spi(0x60); 
adcId = spi(0xFF);    
ADC_CS = 1;
 return adcId; 
}
```

when I print configuration register it is giving value"16383". but when I power off/on the target i am getting "1808(which is equivalent to 0x0710)" after that it is giving same value as"16383". I have tested with different configurations also but it is not changing, always printing "16383" except power off/on.I think default value.

Even with mode register it is always printing"10(which is equivalent to 0x000A)" but that is the value i am getting always, even if I change the configuration to "0x0022".

Even I have tried to read Id register, but it is giving "0x48". but in data sheet it mentioned "0xX8" for AD7798.

Comment: When reading the register, the follwoing code (as posted) makes no sense: `ReadAdConfReg(); printf("configreg:%d",adcConfig);`  - `adcConfig` is local to `ReadAdConfReg()`. So either this code wouldn't compile, or you're printing out an `adcConfig` variable that has nothing to do with the one in `ReadAdConfReg()`.

Comment: Also, first get the reading of the register working - it power on resets to `0x0710`.  Until you can read that value after a reset, you shouldn't worry too much about writing to the register.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I have declared adcConfig as global varial. Sorry for wrong post.

Comment: Can you put a scope or a logic analyzer on the SPI lines?  It's always nice to know how the signals are actually reacting to the code. For example is the SPI clock polarity and phase correct?

Comment: @Michael burr I have added ocsilloscope images. now have a look at.

Comment: I'm not seeing any update with scope images.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
spi(0x07)<<8;
```

must be wrong, it simply shifts the return value of the `spi()` function, a result which is then thrown away.

Comment: Ok then please suggest me how to set ADC configuration register

Answer (score 1):

If I'm correct in assuming that:

- the `spi()` function writes a single byte on the SPI interface
- the interface is MSB first

then you don't need the left-shift...

```
 void setupADC(unsigned char configReg){
     ChipSelectAd(1);  
     spi(0x10);        // register address (including R/Wb bit?)
     spi(0x07);        // data MSB
     spi(0x10);        // data LSB
     spi(configReg);  
     ChipSelectAd(0);  
}
```

I'm not sure how the `spi()` function is used for read and write. Do you have any links to documentation on this?